# Dump Azure Storage Table on unknown Table model

Tags: c#, azure-table-storage

Hi I have the same topic to solve as in the next, I write first time code for azure storage table and failing.

I have not the requirement to dump the table, I need only  the dump with unknown identities only for 1 dataset identified by partitionkey & rowkey.

The following code is from
[Dumping Azure tables quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26008223/dumping-azure-tables-quickly)

```cs
TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity> query = new TableQuery<DynamicTableEntity>();

foreach (DynamicTableEntity entity in table.ExecuteQuery(query))
{
   // Write a dump of the entity (row).
}
```

but this seems deprecated code and the `Execute` function is not callable in new `Azure.Data.Tables`.

I have tried to get access described on this site https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Data.Tables/.

After add table entities I get nothing working. I searched for other code source but I found found no working actual code and failed on adapt them to run.

Please can some post a short code snippet which use an actual data table package.

I have no hard performance requirement, it is for near 100 dataset or little bit more.

But I must change my data model often so I need a dump of all entities from 1 dataset queried by e.g.by an partition key.

I would be very happy if someone could post here a very small working  C# code snippet.

Comment: _After Add table entities I get nothing working_. Can you post the code from the nuget site that you tried, and explain what happened. If an error ocurred please post it. Make sure you check the section on troubleshooting as it shows how to capture and error from the HTTP result

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: sorry there was inconsistency in my project setting . so there is no problem and  I will delete it this entry.

Comment: Even better would be if you post a detailed answer.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid: ok then i can do next weekend, i have some nght session last days  and hard work ne3xt week too. Soi will do do it but not now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example of dumping all the entities from a table without knowing their schema.

```
var service = new TableServiceClient(
        new Uri("https://youraccount.table.core.windows.net"),
        new DefaultAzureCredential());
var table = service.GetTableClient("mytable");

await foreach (var tableEntity in table.QueryAsync<TableEntity>())
{
    Console.WriteLine("--------------------");
    foreach (var kvp in tableEntity)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");
    }
}
```